# how to validate textfield that allows two digits after 

Tags: iphone

i have to validate text field that allows only two digits after `.`

eg:12.34

if user enter more then two digits it won't allows text.

let me know is it understandable or no

how can i done,can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my problem by using this code.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSArray *sep = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    if([sep count]>=2)
    {
        NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
        return !([sepStr length]>2);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should code in the following delegate method,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
 NSArray *sep = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
 if([sep count]==2)
 {
  NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
  if([sepStr length] >2)
  //do whatever you want
 }
}
```

You can also check if they use many decimal points by,

```
if([sep count]>2)
 //use only one decimal point
```

Comment: NSArray *sep = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
  if([sep count]==2)
  {
   
   NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
   if([sepStr length] >2)
   {
    NSLog(@"textfield validating %@",sepStr);

   //do whatever you want
   }
  }
i try this but does n't print any thing

Comment: The if statement will be executed only after the decimal point is encountered

Comment: Check whether you set your delegate

Comment: if i try this NSArray *sep = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
  if([sep count]==2)
  {
   NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
     NSLog(@"hello");
    }
Then it prints when i place . in textfield,but nothing will happen when i place ur above code

Comment: Of course it will check for . symbol then it will check if there is more than 2 digits after . symbol

Answer (score 0):

Check the text validity in text field delegate:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```