# UITextField Setting the Precision

Tags: iphone, ios4

Hey I am using a UITextField to take float value inputs. I am facing a difficulty as I want to restrict during run time, the precision of the values that a user can enter to 2 decimal places. For eg:

Values like 1.11,11.11, 111.11, 1111.11 are permissible 
and
Values like 1.123, 1.111, 1.1111 are not

How could I achieve this without writing too much code. So basically as the decimal point precision hits 2 the user should not be able to increase it to 3. The input field should stop editing there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of UITextFieldDelegate protocol and implement 
`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`

Whenever a character is entered this method is called so in this method check if the entered character is '.' then allow entering only two digits after '.'

From this SO question [how to validate textfield that allows two digits after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934689/how-to-validate-textfield-that-allows-two-digits-after)

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSArray *sep = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    if([sep count]>=2)
    {
        NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
        return !([sepStr length]>2);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see [Restrict UITextField size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216232/restrict-uitextfield-size)

Comment: this doesn't help in dynamic cases. A user should be allowed to enter 1.11 and also 111111.11 but not 1.111

Answer (score 0):

You can have a counter which will be incremented after . is entered and of the counter is greater than 2 => return no :

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

if(string isEqualToString:@"." )
{
 counter++;
}
if(counter>2)
{
    return NO;
}
else
{
return YES;
}
```

}

make counter a global variable.